# Emailing routine on Access form: Runtime Error 3265

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, runtime

I'm putting together an emailing routine on an Access form.

I get a 3265 Error.

This is the bit that causes the error.

```vb
SendToEmail = HyperlinkPart(rs![Client Basics].email, acDisplayedValue)
Cref = rs![Client Basics].[Client Ref]
Cdear = rs![Client Basics].Dear
```

This is the bit of code that is causing the problem.

```vb
Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW Events.[Client Ref], Events.Date, Events.[Event Type], Events.[Event Details], Events.[Advance Code], Events.[Advance Date], Events.Operator, [Client Basics].[Client Ref], [Client Basics].[Client Name],[Client Basics].email, [Client Basics].Dear FROM [Client Basics] INNER JOIN Events ON [Client Basics].[Client Ref] = Events.[Client Ref] WHERE (((Events.[Advance Code])=88) AND ((Events.[Advance Date])<Date()));"
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)


'----------------------------------------------------------Start Email Loop for all Clients Selected -----------------------------------
If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
    rs.MoveFirst
    Do While Not rs.EOF    
        SendToEmail = HyperlinkPart(rs![Client Basics].email, acDisplayedValue)
        Cref = rs![Client Basics].[Client Ref]
        Cdear = rs![Client Basics].Dear
        
        FinalHTML = "<p style=""text-align: right;""><img src=""https://www.accountants.co.uk/logo2.png"" alt="""" /></p><p>Dear " + Cdear + "</p><p>Ref " + Cref + "</p>" + HTMLFile

        Set myMail = myOutlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With myMail
            .To = SendToEmail
            .subject = DigSubject
            .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
            .HTMLBody = FinalHTML
            .Display
        End With
        rs.MoveNext
            
    Loop
End If
    
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set myMail = Nothing
Set myOutlApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Which of those lines causes the error if you step through the code.  Do the fields definitley exist, no typos?

Comment: Surely the error gave you a message, nobody knows all error codes by heart. Help us help you

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's incorrect `rs![Client Basics].[Client Ref]` and `rs![Client Basics].Dear`. There should be nothing after the first closing bracket.

Comment: Sorry, error 3265 - Item cannot be found in Collection. The error is on the first variable, but if I rem it out, the error is the second variable, and again for the third.
I suspect I just don't know the format to pull a variable out of the recordset.

Comment: If `[Client Basics]` is the table name, you don't quote it, only the field name: `rs![Client Ref]`.

Answer (score 0):

I have finally fixed it. I had to add a bit to the SQL Where I had :-

```
[Client Basics].[Client Ref], ......
```

I changed it to

```
[Client Basics].[Client Ref] AS FromRef, .....
```

Then used

```
Cref = rs!FromRef
```